# Need a comparison b/w SAML configuration on Azure AD and ADFS

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

[image: Active directory SAML configuration]

[image]

Equivalent fields of (Entity ID and Reply URL) in ADFS

I am trying to enable on-prem SSO using ADFS , I have Identifier and Reply URL , But Need to know where shall I use these fields in "Relying party trust" in ADFS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the corresponding terms/fields in the configuration wizards

| Azure AD | AD FS | AD FS Wizard Page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Identifier (Entity ID) | Relying party trust identifier | Configure URL |
| Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL) | Relying party SAML 2.0 SSO Service URL | Configure Identifiers |